# JavaScript adding and removing classes not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a sub menu that will only appear when you click on the item in the main menu. I've made a piece of code but it doesn't seem to work there is just no change. I've spent ages trying to get it too work but can't, I would be really grateful if someone could help. I'm trying to avoid using jquery and would like it to be able to have one sub menu open at a time.

this is my js code:

```
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

function menuSlider(subMenu) {
    var el = document.getElementById(subMenu);
    /* Reset all submenu classes */
    document.getElementById("dashboardSubMenu").className = "subMenu dashboardSubMenu";
    document.getElementById("pagesSubMenu").className = "subMenu pagesSubMenu";
    document.getElementById("mediaSubMenu").className = "subMenu mediaSubMenu";
    document.getElementById("styleSubMenu").className = "subMenu stylesSubMenu";
    document.getElementById("settingsSubMenu").className = "subMenu settingsSubMenu";

    if (hasClass(el, 'selected') === false) {
        /* Open submenu */
        document.getElementById(subMenu).className = el.className + ' selected';
    }
}
```

I've got a JSFiddle with the code
http://jsfiddle.net/xR47w/

Comment: sorted now added my js code

Comment: well your fiddle is completely broken due to lack of image links

Comment: I think you're reinventing the wheel... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xR47w/1/. One note, `getElementById("styleSubMenu")` != `getElementById("stylesSubMenu")`

Comment: Also you need to set your fiddle up as "no wrap - body" or else your functions will be local to an "onload" handler and your event handler bindings won't work - keep the console open when debugging!!

Comment: Kevin L just ignore them each missing image symbol would be an image and an item in the menu

Comment: Problem is what @j08691 said, fix the typo and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for all your help its now all fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is in jsfiddle that your code is on the onload event of the page, and since you use the `onclick` approach you function must be global. So change from the dropdown where you code is put.

Then you have a wrong name in one of the `id`s

```
document.getElementById("styleSubMenu").className
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("stylesSubMenu").className
```

(*missing the `s` in `styles`*)

That cause a syntax error and your code that checks the classes was never reached.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xR47w/4/